# Convert Windows Phone 7 app to eclipse for android

Tags: java, android

First off I need to tell you that I am new to java I have only been using it for a bout 3 weeks. I am putting together an app for our Electrical / instrumentation apprentices.
I developed an app using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 7; unfortunately I am unable to run the app on a test phone with out paying Microsoft for a developer’s license for each phone at a cost of $100.00ea. 
Is it possible to import and convert a Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 7 app in to eclipse and convert it for android?
Please tell me that this is easy to do!
Thanks

Comment: Did you write your app in C#? If so, C# is just Microsoft's rip-off of Java. If you're any good at coding then just run through some Android tutorials, work out how it works then copy / paste your code into an Android project.

Comment: yes it in C# but i have only been using C# for a few weeks, my main for the last few years has been VBA or VB. i am currently trying Eclipse for Android, but the graphic side of it is Treble to Handel. i used Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone 7 to create it. the graphic layout is really good.

Comment: OK. I wasn't joking about C# being a rip-off of Java though. There are some significant differences but they're both part of the 'C' family of languages. Obviously your down-side is using visual tools - eclipse  & ADT is quite clunky. It might be worth trying Android Studio which has a better UI design ability but is in a 'preview' stage.

Comment: thanks for that i have tried it but it keeps having problems and i find the GUI is not a lot different, i cannot believe that professional developers use eclipse for Android to develop all the apps i see on the web. there must be a much better developer platform? that is more GUI reliable, and easy to use. and a lot more stable.

Comment: To be honest I rarely use the graphical layout tools of eclipse and just create layouts directly in XML. I test the layouts on my phone and my tablet and if I haven't got them quite right I make minor adjustments. I believe there are 3rd party tools out their for 'visual' development of Android layouts but you'd have to Google for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  There's no easy conversion.  It's a completely different language and system.

Your best bet is probably to load it into something like Xamarin and divide out your business logic into data classes, and learn the Android bits of Xamarin.

There's a ton of [tutorials](http://xamarin.com/getting-started/android) out there for using Xamarin's Android platform.

Comment: thanks for the info i had a look at Xamarin but could not get it to run on my system. but thanks anyway, i will attempt to rewight it.